# JS Array Filter Function - Return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Not using ES6 (arrow syntax), does the filter function need a return? If it does, can I consolidate these 2 filter() into one?

```
cars.filter(function(car, index) { 
  return car[0].setAttribute("data-original-position", index) 
});

cars.filter(function(car) { 
  return car[0].setAttribute("data-preferred", "N") 
});
```

Comment: If you need to double filter, one immediately after the other, you've probably chosen the wrong Array.method.

Comment: `filter()` does need a return, but it looks like you're not using the method correctly anyway as you're not using the logic in the function to restrict the data in the array. `forEach()` may be more to your needs, however the fact that you're using `car[0]` means you don't even need a loop at all.

Comment: Look for `forEach()`.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you're trying to do.  Give us example input and expected output and take it from there.  You appear to be using `filter()` for something that's it's not intended for.

Comment: You're updating the same `car[0]` array-element on *every* iteration of the `filter()` method (which, as others have said, is the wrong method for what's going on); why?

Comment: Sorry, that was one worst answer I wrote. Didn't expect it came out of me. `:(` I guess I am too drunk (in dreams).

Comment: @DavidThomas No he's not. Car is one value from that array and index is the index of the car in the cars array.

Comment: @FINDarkside: I must be overlooking something, then, since I read the line `car[0].setAttribute('data-original-position', index)` as overwriting the attribute of the same first array-element in each iteration with the index of the current array element on each iteration.

Comment: @DavidThomas car is cars[index]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does need a `return` since you're not using ES6 arrow functions, which, have implicit returns.

Furthermore, you're using `filter` as an iterator - while it works you could argue that you're not using it correctly and will most likely confuse yourself and other colleagues when they come across this code.

A normal for loop would be better and more readable.

```
for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    cars[i].setAttribute("data-original-position", index);
    cars[i].setAttribute("data-preferred", "N");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't map() also need a return? If using map, how can I do both setAttributes?

Comment: `map()` is not right either since no array is being produced. `forEach()` is th method he’s looking for.

Comment: `.map()` also needs a return, you're using normal functions so they always need to return.

Comment: @Mark_M It all depends, right? The point im trying to make is that filter isn't the right since it doesn't boil down to an X amount of cars. A map over `cars` would be OK since it'd transform each car inside the array into a new array with modified cars. Cars represented by DOMNodes in this case.

Comment: I suppose if you need to modify elements *and* you want two arrays pointing at the same elements. In your `map()` example, `cars` and `newCars` are two arrays pointing at the same modified objects.

Comment: using `map` still doesnt make sense if you mutate the original array. Whatsoever the best answer so far.

Comment: Removed section about `.map()` since it drew too much attention from the point I was trying to make :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `filter` needs to return a falsy or truthy value. 
In your case your functions always return undefined because of `setAttribute`.
If you return a truthy value then a value goes in a new array.

Answer (score 0):

`myArray.filter(predicateFunction)` returns an array containing all elements for that `predicateFunction(element)` returns `true`.

Example:

```
function predicateFunction(element) {
  return element === 'red'
}
const myArray = ['red', 'blue'];
const filteredArray = myArray.filter(predicateFunction);
console.log(filteredArray) // => returns ['red']
```

Hence, `predicateFunction` needs to return a boolean. If you use arrow functions without curly braces (with only one statement), they will have an implicit return.

In your case `car[0].setAttribute("data-preferred", "N")` does not seem to return a boolean. `filter` might not be the correct method for you. Depending on what you need, you might want to look into a `for` loop instead.